# API getting answers in array and display values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

This seems like such a rookie question but I'm just banging my head against the keyboard here and I can't find anything answered already that gets me moving forward.

This is my PHP:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8;'); 
$url = file_get_contents("https://example.org/subdomain/api.php?t=t&q=maria");
print_r(json_decode($url));
?>
```

This is the results:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [apiVersion] => 1
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 47
                    [by] => 5
                    [title] => WATER
                    ...
                 )
            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 45
                    [by] => 5
                    [title] => HEARTH
                    ...
                 )
      ...
```

**How could I extract and echo the property `title`?**

I tried this without success (error 500, blank page)

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8;'); 

$url = 'https://example.org/subdomain/api.php?t=t&q=maria';
$json = file_get_contents($url);

$answersArray = Array();
for($i=0;$i<count($jsonArray['data']);$i++){
    array_push($answersArray,$jsonArray['data'][$i]['title']);
}
```

**UPDATE**

I tried also with this code, still no luck

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8;'); 

$url = 'https://example.org/subdomain/api.php?t=t&q=maria';
$json = file_get_contents($url);

$answersArray = Array();
for($i=0;$i<count($jsonArray['data']);$i++){
    array_push(echo $answersArray,$jsonArray['data'][$i]->title);

}
foreach($answersArray as $answer) {
    echo $answer;
}
?>
```

Comment: 1) You need to decode your json data 2) Simply loop through your subArray `data` 3) Return the property title for each object: `$titles = array_map(function($v){return $v->title;}, json_decode($json)["data"]);`

Comment: @Rizier123 Thanks, I tried with this but it's still not working `$json = file_get_contents($url);

$data = json_decode($json);

foreach($data as $key => $subarray) {
     $titles = array_map(function($v){return $v->title;}, json_decode($json)["data"]);
}`

Comment: Just use the code above no foreach loop.

Comment: @Rizier123 I tried but I get 500 internal server error

Comment: Add error reporting: `ini_set("display_errors", 1);
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your file(s) and tell us if you get any + check your error logs and tell what you get. (Also what is the output of: `echo PHP_VERSION;` ?)

Comment: @Rizier123 PHP version is `5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11` and the error message is `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: Check if you have: [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) enabled (`echo ini_get("allow_url_fopen");`)

Comment: @Rizier123 I checked the php.ini file and it's already ON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your errors lies in the utilization of the `json_decode` function... you need to specify `true` as the second argument to actually get an array instead of an object.

```php
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8;'); 
$url = file_get_contents("https://example.org/subdomain/api.php?t=t&q=maria");
print_r(json_decode($url, true));
```

And then, if you use the foreach, or better, `array_column` (php 5.5), you can fetch the title property of each object.

```php
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8;'); 
$url = file_get_contents("https://example.org/subdomain/api.php?t=t&q=maria");
$response = json_decode($url, true);

$titles = array_column($response['data'], 'title');
var_dump($titles);
```

Comment: your solution give me the word "NULL" displaying in page, nothing else

Comment: Sorry, made a typo, which I just fixed !

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're trying to access an object property like an array:

```
array_push($answersArray,$jsonArray->data[$i]['title']);
```

should be:

```
array_push($answersArray,$jsonArray->data[$i]->title);
```

To output the titles later you can use the following:

```
foreach($answersArray as $answer) {
    echo $answer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks there are no more errors but I'm unable to echo...how could I display only each `title`?

Comment: @Simone Where are you trying to echo? Your code only shows that you are storing each title in the `$answersArray`. You can loop that to echo each title.

Comment: I tried outside the loop to echo `$answersArray` but the results is the word "array"

Comment: @Simone I've added a simple example for echoing each title from the array.

Comment: no data shown, only a white page, and from console I got `500 server error`...I updated the question with my code

Comment: @Simone you are not decoding the json as you were in your first example.

Comment: the ``$jsonArray`` is not an array, it is a stdClass, So you should do ``$jsonArray->data`` instead of ``$jsonArray['data']`` (That's why I downvoted)

Comment: @Talus thanks for pointing that out, I completely skimmed past it! Updated the answer, and will keep a keener eye next time around.

Comment: Now that it looks legit, I changed my downvote to a upvote, even though I suggested using the second parameter of `json_decode` to true :}

Answer (score 2):

Basic steps

- Decode the JSON.
- Get array at 'data' property.
- Iterate the 'data' array.
- Load title property for each 'data' item into new array.

Code example:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8;');

$url = 'https://example.org/subdomain/api.php?t=t&q=maria';
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($json);
$data = $obj->data; // get data array
$titles = array();

foreach ($data as $item) {
    $titles[] = $item->title;
}
print_r($titles);
?>
```

Comment: Hi, I don't know why but with this solution I get the 500 internal server error

Comment: GET https://example.org/subdomain/prova.php 500 (Internal Server Error) ...prova.php:1

Comment: Who upvoted this?  You don't access a property with `.` in PHP

Comment: @Rizier123 Stupid typo for me, been doing a lot of javascripting lately :).  It is now corrected.  Concept remains the same.

Comment: thanks, I just used `echo implode(',', $titles);` to display results in comma separated list

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
 $json=file_get_contents("https://2b4bxi178h.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dev/h");
      $weather=json_decode($json,true);   


          foreach ([''] as $key => $value) {
             $temperature= $value['Robot_No']['Table_Clean'];
             echo "$temperature";
           }
?>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please include a brief description of how this code solves the problem.